# Javascript JSON object reorder

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I've got the following JSON:

```
var obj = 
{
  "workers": [
    {
      "TimeStamp": "2020-03-13T10:08",
      "Status": "status1",
      "Name": "one",
      "Number": 19.9
    },
    {
      "TimeStamp": "2019-07-19T06:01",
      "Status": "status2",
      "Name": "one",
      "Number": 9
    },
    {
      "TimeStamp": "2020-04-22T05:10",
      "Status": "status2",
      "Name": "one",
      "Number": 10.1
    },
    {
      "TimeStamp": "2019-07-21T23:53",
      "Status": "status2",
      "Name": "two",
      "Number": 16.3 
    },
    {
      "TimeStamp": "2019-11-21T05:14",
      "Status": "status1",
      "Name": "three",
      "Number": 122.54
    },
    ...
  ]
};
```

As you see there's just 2 different status possible: "status1" and "status2".
Names should be filtered to be shown just once, but combine the two different status. 
The respective status should include the "TimeStamp" and "Number" in an array.

In the end it should look like this:

```
{
  "workers": [
    {
      "Name":"one",
      "status1": [
        {
          "TimeStamp":"2020-03-13T10:08",
          "Number": 19.9
        }
      ],
      "status2": [
        {
          "TimeStamp":"2019-07-19T06:01",
          "Number": 9
        },
        {
          "TimeStamp": "2020-04-22T05:10",
          "Number": 10.1
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name":"two",
      "status1": [],
      "status2": [
        {
          "TimeStamp":"2019-07-21T23:53",
          "Number": 16.3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name":"three",
      "status1": [
        {
          "TimeStamp":"2019-11-21T05:14",
          "Number": 122.54
        }
      ],
      "status2": []
     }
  ]
}
```

I tried out the following so far:

```
var writeObj = { 'workers': [] };

for (var i = 0; i < obj.workers.length; i++) {
    if(!Object.values(writeObj.workers).includes(obj.workers[i].Name)) {

        writeObj['workers'].push({ Name: obj.workers[i].Name, 'status1': [], 'status2': [] });
        for (var j = 0; j < obj.workers.length; j++) {
            if (obj.workers[j].Name === obj.workers[i].Name && obj.workers[j].Status === 'status1') {
                writeObj['workers'][i]['status1'].push({ TimeStamp: obj.workers[j].TimeStamp, Number: obj.workers[j].Number });
            } else if (obj.workers[j].Name === obj.workers[i].Name && obj.workers[j].Status === 'status2') {
                writeObj['workers'][i]['status2'].push({ TimeStamp: obj.workers[j].TimeStamp, Number: obj.workers[j].Number });
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

I'm stuck and can't see the mistake...
Thanks for any help!

Comment: What's the result you've seen so far with the code you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). Group by the `Name` key according to your format, then take the grouped values as the result. Time complexity is O(n).

```js
var obj = { "workers": [ { "TimeStamp": "2020-03-13T10:08", "Status": "status1", "Name": "one", "Number": 19.9 }, { "TimeStamp": "2019-07-19T06:01", "Status": "status2", "Name": "one", "Number": 9 }, { "TimeStamp": "2020-04-22T05:10", "Status": "status2", "Name": "one", "Number": 10.1 }, { "TimeStamp": "2019-07-21T23:53", "Status": "status2", "Name": "two", "Number": 16.3 }, { "TimeStamp": "2019-11-21T05:14", "Status": "status1", "Name": "three", "Number": 122.54 }, ] };

const grouped = Object.values(obj.workers.reduce((a, e) => {
  if (!a[e.Name]) {
    a[e.Name] = {Name: e.Name, status1: [], status2: []};
  }
  
  a[e.Name][e.Status].push({TimeStamp: e.TimeStamp, Number: e.Number});
  return a;
}, {})); 

console.log(grouped);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can aggregate your data using [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
var obj = 
{
  "workers": [
    {
      "TimeStamp": "2020-03-13T10:08",
      "Status": "status1",
      "Name": "one",
      "Number": 19.9
    },
    {
      "TimeStamp": "2019-07-19T06:01",
      "Status": "status2",
      "Name": "one",
      "Number": 9
    },
    {
      "TimeStamp": "2020-04-22T05:10",
      "Status": "status2",
      "Name": "one",
      "Number": 10.1
    },
    {
      "TimeStamp": "2019-07-21T23:53",
      "Status": "status2",
      "Name": "two",
      "Number": 16.3 
    },
    {
      "TimeStamp": "2019-11-21T05:14",
      "Status": "status1",
      "Name": "three",
      "Number": 122.54
    }
  ]
};

let output = obj.workers.reduce((acc,cur) => {
    let {Name, Status, ...rest} = cur;
    let match = acc.find(x => x.Name === Name);
    if(!match){
       match = { Name: Name };
       acc.push(match);
    }
    if(!match[Status]){
       match[Status] = [];
    }
    match[Status].push(rest);
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log({workers: output});
```